# ngrx platform - how to install the entire bundle

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm a bit confused about the mono repo that is ngrx platform.
How do I install the entire collection? Is there a npm install command to install it or do I have to install each one (store, effects,..) individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install each one individually.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/router-store/README.md
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store-devtools/README.md